# catching response of post request after post's succeeded

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js, post

I am creating a post request and it's executing successfully and I can see that response in the network tab.

I am trying to store that response so that I can use that further ahead, but I am not able to do so. I don't exactly know how can I store that response, can anyone guide me about that?

I have created a post like below sample and I was trying to put `.then` after but I think it just hadn't worked for me.

```
const current = api();
await current.post(`/sampleUrl`,formData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I do not know what's your current stack for managing XHR requests, I make a general example supposing your abstraction returns a *promise*:

```
const current = api();

getAPI = async () => {
    let res = await current.post(`/sampleUrl`,formData);
    let { data } = await res.data;
    console.log(data); // logs the response
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Which module are you using for POST requests?

In [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) this saves the response. This might do it for you.

```
const request = require("request");
const response = request.post(data);
```

Comment: hi @lil-b       i am not sure about your answer got to check that, if i store my post request it can be used further to achieve what i want. 
anyways i appreciate your suggestion thank you :-)